# Get File Last Modify Time and Compare

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I want a piece of function which will take a file and last how many days, if it was older than that date, will return 0 otherwise 1... Something like that...

For example:

```
int IsOlder(TCHAR *filename, int days)
{

do operation.

If last modify date was older than days variable
return 0
else
return 1

}
```

It's MS VC++ 6 for Windows.
Thanks from now!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Windows has an API function called `GetFileTime()` ([doc on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724320(VS.85).aspx)) taking a file handle in parameter and 3 `FILETIME` structures to be filled with date-time info:

```
FILETIME creationTime,
         lpLastAccessTime,
         lastWriteTime;
bool err = GetFileTime( h, &creationTime, &lpLastAccessTime, &lastWriteTime );
if( !err ) error
```

The `FILETIME` structure is obfuscated, use the function `FileTimeToSystemTime()` to translate it to a `SYSTEMTIME` structure which is way easier to use:

```
SYSTEMTIME systemTime;
bool res = FileTimeToSystemTime( &creationTime, &systemTime );
if( !res ) error
```

Then you can use fields `wYear`, `wMonth`, etc. to compare with your number of days.

Answer (score 2):

[GetFileTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724320(VS.85).aspx) gets the various dates relevant to a file. There's an [example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724926(VS.85).aspx).

You will need to fetch the last write time, and calculate the difference in days from there. As the `GetFileTime` function returns the quite unwieldy `FILETIME` structure you probably want to convert it into system time (`struct SYSTEMTIME`) with `FileTimeToSystemTime`.