# Last write FILETIME always returning current time

Tags: c++, datetime, winapi, windows-8.1, c++builder-xe7

I need to compare a file's last modified time to a date time stored in a database.  I initially looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1938939/get-file-last-modify-time-and-compare) to get started.

I am currently getting the `FILETIME` for the last write of the file, converting it to a `SYSTEMTIME`. Then I use that `SYSTEMTIME` to create a `TDateTime` object that I can use for my comparison.  However, the `FileModifiedDT` variable, is always coming out to be the current time, despite the file having been modified previously.

```
FILETIME lastWriteTime;

String * FileNamePtr = new String( FileName );

GetFileTime( FileNamePtr, NULL, NULL, &lastWriteTime );

SYSTEMTIME systemTime;
FileTimeToSystemTime( &lastWriteTime, &systemTime );

TDateTime * FileModifiedDT = new TDateTime( systemTime.wYear, systemTime.wMonth,
                                            systemTime.wDay, systemTime.wHour,
                                            systemTime.wMinute, systemTime.wSecond,
                                            systemTime.wMilliseconds );
```

Am I missusing `GetFileTime` in some way?  Is there a better way I should go about this?

Comment: which windows system are you on?

Comment: windows 8.1 Pro 64bit

Comment: is `GetFileTime` successful? try with `if(....)`

Comment: Looks like `GetFileTime` is NOT successful.  How can I figure out what error I am getting with it?

Comment: [GetFileTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724320.aspx): *"If the function fails, the return value is zero. To get extended error information, call [**GetLastError**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679360.aspx)."*

Comment: follow instructions here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/455434/how-should-i-use-formatmessage-properly-in-c/455533#455533

Comment: I am getting back the error code '6' which seems to mean invalid handle.  Would that be referring to my `FileNamePtr` ?

Comment: Yes. You'll need to pass a `HANDLE` obtained from a call to `CreateFile`, not a path name.

Comment: On a side note, stop using pointers for types that don't need it: `String sFileName = FileName; ... TDateTime FileModifiedDT( systemTime.wYear, systemTime.wMonth, systemTime.wDay, systemTime.wHour, systemTime.wMinute, systemTime.wSecond, systemTime.wMilliseconds );`. In the case of converting a `SYSTEMTIME` to a `TDateTime`, the RTL has a `SystemTimeToDateTime()` function: `TDateTime FileModifiedDT = SystemTimeToDateTime( systemTime );`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error is

```
String * FileNamePtr = new String( FileName );
GetFileTime( FileNamePtr, NULL, NULL, &lastWriteTime );
```

According to the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724320(v=vs.85).aspx), the first argument has to be a file handle created by `CreateFile` and nothing else.

Thus you need something like this:

```
HANDLE fileHandle = CreateFile(
  FileName, //LPCTSTR
  GENERIC_READ,
  FILE_SHARE_READ,
  NULL,
  OPEN_EXISTING,
  FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
  NULL
);

if ( fileHandle != INVALID_HANDLE )
{
    GetFileTime( fileHandle, NULL, NULL, &lastWriteTime );
    CloseHandle( fileHandle );
}
else
{
    // error, do something else...
}
```

Comment: If you don't want to open the file, you can use `FindFirstFile()` (wrapped by C++Builder's `Sysutils::FindFirst()` function) or `GetFileAttributesEx()` instead.